# Как составить уникальные слова из массива?

Tags: php, массивы

Есть 3 - 5 массивов, в которых содержится n-ое количество слогов.

Как обработать эти массивы и получить уникальные (не повторяющие) слова?

Каждый массив - это отдельная часть слова. Первый массив - начало, второй - середина, третий - конец.

Читабельность слов не важна, главное - их уникальность.

Comment: array_unique($array)

Comment: @J.Doe array_unique вроде удаляет повторения в массиве. А мне нужно составить слова, где и начало и середина могут быть одинаковыми. Главное условие - чтобы это было один раз и больше не повторялось.

Comment: Если для каждого массива сделать array_unique, то их декартово произведение будет содержать только уникальные элементы

Comment: @MBo не совсем понимаю логики

Comment: @Eva_m А что такое декартово произведение (cartestian product) массивов/списков - знаете? Про достаточность очистки от дубликатов начальных массивов я поспешил - это не сработает, если, например, слоги в первом массиве ["фыва","фыв"], а во втором ["прол","апрол"], так что надо и конечный массив чистить, или сразу строить trie или другую структуру, гарантирующую уникальность.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-diff-assoc.php
http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-diff.php

Если я правильно понял задачу. 
В каждую из функций можно много массивов подать, на выходе будут только уникальные значения.

Answer (score 1):

Например, можно так:

1. Слить все массивы
2. Перемешать элементы массива
3. Разбить полученный массив на части случайным образом
4. Преобразовать эти части в строку *(слово)* и сохранить в массив
5. Удалить повторы из массива *(если они есть)*

Решение:

```
$start = [
    'нен',
    'но',
    'был',
    'ту',
    'уста',
    'над'
];

$middle = [
    'вер',
    'наро',
    'не',
    'даолр',
];

$end = [
    'ног',
    'и',
    'лиш',
    'ним',
    'ок'
];

$words = array_merge($start, $middle, $end);
shuffle($words);

$words = array_map(function($a){
    return join($a);
}, array_chunk($words, mt_rand(2, 5)));

$words = array_unique($words);

var_dump($words);
```

Comment: @Eva_m не стоит благодарности )